# Twilio web-hook implementation using custom object

Tags: php, twilio-api, twilio-php

Ideally, the case is when we send SMS to members they should be replying back and we have configured the web-hook but in the web-hook, we would like to receive a custom array or object as well this way we can redirect that text or reply of SMS to a specific group.

```
  $account_sid = '<SID>';
    $auth_token = '<AUTH_TOKEN>';
    // In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
    // $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]

    // A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
    $twilio_number = "<TWILIO_NUMBER>";
    
    $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
    $result = $client->messages->create(
        // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
        '<TO_NUMBER>',
        array(
            'from' => $twilio_number,
            'body' => 'Hello!!'
        )
    );
```

[image]

I have set message webhook so, when someone should reply on my message I can come to know via web-hook.

following is the response that I got from Twillio.

Now I want something like when someone will reply to my SMS i should get group id and other things so I can handle the object in my code.
[image]

Comment: Can you look up the group based on the sending number?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, I did not get you properly. The case is when a post has created the members associated with the post will receive SMS. so when a member has replied on the SMS sent then the reply message should get append as post comment.So if will be great if we get back some post_id so I can easily append that reply as comment of the post.

Comment: For outgoing SMSs, you can specify a custom webhook endpoint, but that is only to receive status updates. For incoming SMSs, you have only 1 global webhook URL (per Twilio number) - no way to eg specify different `group_id`s in the URL, or anything like that. So all you have is the sender's number, the msg, and the receiving number. If you store your users' phone numbers, then you can try to match the senders number to a user, which maybe gives you the group.  If that doesn't work, maybe you can request users include some txt in the msg body, like `GROUP1`.  Or lastly maybe ...

Comment: ... you could have 1 Twilio number for each group.  Each Twilio number can have a different webhook, eg `/sms/incoming/group_1`, etc.